# Sprint board columns not getting resized with story cards

Tags: multiple-columns, autoresize, sprint

On my sprint board in ADO the column size is not getting resized as per size of story cards.

Not getting any option to resize column size on sprint board.
The story cards looks larger than column width and enters in another column and all cards looks clumsy on board.